# Can I purchase a friend's Metro ticket and mine with only my ID?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, paris

There will be two of us traveling on a Tuesday thru Monday several times on the Metro, zones 1-5. (Paris) I'm confused about the best type of ticket to purchase.  We could use it up to 3 times a day, but probably not more than that.

Also, I saw with one type of ticket, one needs to have a photo ID of a certain size.  I plan on arriving at the airport earlier than my friend, so can I purchase his Metro ticket and mine with only my ID?

Comment: When I worked it out a few years ago, up to three times per day the set of 10 tickets was cheaper than a pass. Google metro paris prices and you will get all options.

Answer (score 2):

> so can I purchase his Metro ticket and mine with only my ID?

No, the photograph is attached to the pass - and needs to match the user (from [Paris by Train](http://parisbytrain.com/tag/paris-metro-pass/)):

> **How to buy Navigo Découverte pass**
>
> You can buy a Navigo Découverte pass at nearly any Metro, RER, Transilien train ticket window that normally sells tickets and passes. (I say “nearly” because a ticket window may run out of blank Navigo passes to sell you.) You’ll need a smaller than passport size photo to be used on the pass (exact Navigo Decouverte photo size is 3cm tall by 2.5cm wide), plus a pen to write your name. There’s nearly always a photo booth nearby ticket windows at major stations, costing 5€ for a set of four pictures, so be sure to get your photo taken before going to the ticket window where they’ll likely have scissors handy for trimming your freshly minted photo on the pass. If you’re hesitant in how to ask to buy the pass at a ticket window, try printing out this page and showing the ticket seller the image of the Découverte card on the top right while holding up your small headshot photo. I’m pretty sure the ticket seller will get the idea.

Comment: I seem to remeber that Paris visite pass(I think valid for airports) and ticket mobilis(not valid for airport) can be purchased from vending machines without an ID.